# How can i replace html data with a json array using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to replace the data on a products page i'm working on using ajax. I've gotten the data from php as an array but when i try to use the each iterator on jquery on the last row from the json array is used. I'm assuming it replaces all the   necessary html fields with each item from the json array instead of replacing just one field with one item.
Jquery code is below..the image source is gotten from the database and is supposed to replace the current image source

```
$.get('product2.php', function (data) {
    // console.log(data);
    var output = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(output, function () {
        console.log(1);
        var productname = this['name'];
        var productImage = "data/" + this['image'];
        var productPrice = this['unit_price'];
        var productId = this['id'];
        if (output) {

            $('.productimg').attr('src', productImage);
        }

    });
    console.log(output);
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
    <!-- Block2 -->
    <div class="block2">
        <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative block2-labelnew">
            <img id='<?php echo "data/$row[id]"; ?>' class="productimg " height="300px"
                src='<?php echo "data/$row[image]"; ?>' alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

            <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
                <a href="#" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
                    <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>

                <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-id="1" data-name="product 1"
                        data-summary="summary 1" data-price="10" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_1.png">
                        Add to Cart
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the page has 12 of this divs generated from another page after querying the database.
I'ts a personal project i'm trying to work on
here are some pictures

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will be help you

$.get('product2.php', function (data) {

```
    var html = '';   
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);   
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {  
        var productname = value.name;
        var productImage = "images/" + value.image;
        var productPrice = value.unit_price;
        var productId = value.id;
        html += '<img class="productimg" height="300px" src="' + productImage + '">';
    });
    $('.productimg').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.productimg').attr('src', productImage);`
This line of code will replace all your images with the last image in the array because you are using the same class for all `<img>` tags

instead use the following piece of code

```
$(image_id).attr('src', productImage);
```

where `image_id` should be the HTML id of the `<img>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use JavaScript Dot notation, as JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, it works the same as any other JavaScript object.

This means that you can do this:

```
<script>
//Out JSON string:
var ProductJSON = {
    "Productname": "Box of code",
    "Price": 5.50,
    "Weitght": 15,
    "isMetric": true
}

//Putting it in HTML with JS (the ugly way)
document.write("ProductName: " + ProductJSON.Productname );
document.write("Price: "       + ProductJSON.Price);
document.write("Weitght: "     + ProductJSON.Weitght);
</script>
```

If I understand your code correctly, you are overwriting your variables. You could define your variables as an array, and looping through those to create new elements.

I hope this will nudge you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using class as selector `$('.productimg').attr('src', productImage);` will change all image, because multiple  tag's have the same **class** name, to change image of particular  tag use **id** `$('#'+productId ).attr('src', productImage);`.